# Changing the location where tmux saves sessions?

Tags: terminal, tmux

I often connect to a terminal on my school's network. Anything higher than my home directory I cannot change. Is there a command for the .tmux.conf that would allow me to save my sessions in directory inside of my home directory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By default tmux does not save its session. You need a plugin like [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator) or [tmux-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect).

If you [use tmux-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect) plugin to save your session. It saves by default into `~/.tmux/resurrect` directory. You can customize the location [by adding this](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect/blob/master/docs/save_dir.md) to your `.tmux.conf`

```
set -g @resurrect-dir '/some/path'
```

[tmux-resurrect](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect) can be combined with [tmux-continuum](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum) to add auto-save and restore features.

> Features:
>
> - continuous saving of tmux environment
> - automatic tmux start when computer/server is turned on
> - automatic restore when tmux is started

Comment: Can that path be `'~/.dotfiles/tmux/resurrect/'`. I've created that directory but it keeps saving in the previous one. Ok I forgot to reload tmux config.